# CMS for Blog site

Tags: cms, blog

I would like to create a blog site with features like Engadget.  The editor can upload blog and albums while users can comment.  I know it's even easier to use blogspot but it's blocked in China.

I have tried Joomla before.  It seems a bit slow even after removing most of the modules and the memcache plugin doesn't help much either.  Is there any other option?  Do I need other plugins to run WordPress as blog?

Comment: If a barebone Joomla install is slow, even with memcached, then you may want to switch web hosts.

Comment: Joomla is ALWAYS slow, it's not the host.

Comment: The latest figures I've seen showed Joomla as being the slowest out of Drupal, Joomla, and Wordpress. However, it's only about 20% slower than Wordpress, which is the fastest out of the bunch. On a decent shared hosting plan, Joomla should run at reasonable speeds, and there wouldn't be any perceptual difference between the three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use WordPress. You don't need anything other than what comes out of the box (unless you want a different theme, than you just need to upload it the /wp-content/themes directory).

Comment: in fact, I tried wordpress and found that wix is even easier.  More customization without a line of code.  However, it's blocked by the great firewall of China.  So I have to revert back to WP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a blog with a smallish amount of content pages and a large amount of blog updates use Wordpress.  If you're looking for increased functionality with lots of unique feature requirements then you might want to look at Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, WordPress is by far the easiest to use but is more prone to spam attacks. Drupal on the other hand is more robust, has a large community and various plugins etc like Wordpress. But Drupal is far harder to customise design wise than WordPress.

If it's just a blog site as you say it is, I'd go for WordPress, especially as you have the option of hosting it with WordPress rather than on your own server (if you havent got one).

Answer (score 0):

http://ikiwiki.info can suit your needs if the blog doesn't update every instant, and want to save computing resources.

It's a site compiler (wiki, blog), i.e., it is run once after every update to compile static web pages.